# How gmail android App loads its ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contentprovider

How **gmail** app does its loading ? does it use an ArrayAdapter(store the data in memory) or store the data in a sqlLite database as a source for its **ListView**.

Ps: Nexus 5 got hanged when I kept loading the **gmail** emails for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely use `LoaderManager` and load the rows from the internal database.

Emails are stored in internal database. You can see the rows and columns of the tables of the database using Root Explorer and proper `SQLite` viewer.

It also uses `SyncAdapter` to fill the database from the cloud. This is the most efficient way.

You can check LoaderManager here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

And if you want to do the same and you want to create `ContentProvider` with a `SQLite` database you should try this: https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/ProviGen

Comment: Sounds like a definite answer. How many rows are stored in the database ?

Comment: Rows? There are lots of tables in that database. Lots of columns as well. The biggest table should be the one with the email contents and the row number should be the same as the number of total emails stored